# MySQL config tuning for long running queries

Tags: mysql

I have a SELECT query that takes around 2 minutes to run. It is causing our app to hang on the new cloud DB we migrated it to. The new cloud DB has only 3.5 GB of memory and 1 vCPU.

On our old VM DB it takes only `0.6` seconds which has around 16GB of memory.

Sometimes the SELECT query causes 100% CPU usage usually. And it looks like other queries don't get executed when this long running query is running.

`569 rows in set (1 min 52.23 sec)`

Is there anything I can configure to tune the my.cnf to return better results and mainly to prevent app from hanging. These are the only settings I have right now.

```
open_files_limit = 102400
max_connections = 5000
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2800M
innodb_log_file_size=600M
innodb_rollback_on_timeout=ON
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
```

Its a query that returns the number of friends. And some of them might have around 600 friends and getting that list is what causing the issue. We can't change the query at the moment since its hardcoded to the app. But looking at the query it seems optimzed.

Comment: I would start with the query.

Comment: You should strive to make the query visit as few rows as possible. If you have subqueries - try to limit their output with WHERE inside the subquery rather than outside. IF you have JOINs - try to start with the table with fewest rows and then join other tables in the order of increasing number of rows. If this is an analytics type of query - try to run it on a different copy of the DB rather than on production.

Comment: wow 600 what a big number for a relational datable (sorry for the sarcasm but I couldn't stand it)

Comment: lol yea :) I had to mention that so you know how bad the current DB status is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Had to rebuild indexes and that fixes the issue. After the dump was imported I ran the command `mysqlcheck database_name -p --optimize` then the issue was resolved.

The query is now performing well, CPU usage has decreased, memory is being consumed, and query caching is also working.